# Input won't align in list Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a list in Ionic, and I've added a second **< input >** for each line as you can see.

I want to align the text on that input to the right. 
As you can see in the image I've attached, the column in the middle with the %
won't align.

```
<div class="list list-inset">
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">-/50 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_50" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_50" name="-/50 mm" 
placeholder="0" style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>                
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">50/60 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_50_60" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_50_60" name="50/60 mm" placeholder="0"        
style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>                
<label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">60/70 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_60_70" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_60_70" name="60/70 mm" 
placeholder="0" style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>  
</div>
```

[image]

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/oXvxYE)

Answer (score 0):

Your screen shot does not correspond to your code. Also, there are more efficient ways to do what you are trying to do. A table for instance. Anyways, the reason why you are not getting what you expect is because you have not set the display type on elements accordingly. Also, do NOT do inline css. That should get you started.

```css
.item{
  display: block;
}

span, input{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  
  /* Make it look like your screen shoot*/
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin: 5px 12.5px;
  text-align: right;
}
.input-label1{
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list list-inset">
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label1">-/50 mm</span>
  <input type="text" id="prc_mm_50" value="Some text" disabled/>
  <input type="number" id="mm_50" name="-/50 mm" placeholder="0" value="50"/>       
</label>                
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label1">50/60 mm</span>
  <input type="text" id="prc_mm_50_60" value="Some other text" disabled/>   
  <input type="number" id="mm_50_60" name="50/60 mm" placeholder="0" />         
</label>                
<label class="item item-input">
  <span class="input-label1">60/70 mm</span>
  <input type="text" id="prc_mm_60_70" disabled/> 
  <input type="number" id="mm_60_70" name="60/70 mm" placeholder="0" />           
</label>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's okay for you to define a fixed left position for that middle input element, you can add this CSS rule:

```
div.list.list-inset>.item.item-input span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}
```

It fixes th width of the `span` inside the `label`, thereby giving all middle input elements the same position from the left.. You have to try around to find a px setting that fits you in all situations. But instead of a pixel value you could also use a percentage value.

```css
div.list.list-inset>.item.item-input span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
}

div.list.list-inset > *{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list list-inset">
  <label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">-/50 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_50" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_50" name="-/50 mm" 
placeholder="0" style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>
  <label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">50/60 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_50_60" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_50_60" name="50/60 mm" placeholder="0"        
style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>
  <label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">60/70 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_60_70" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_60_70" name="60/70 mm" 
placeholder="0" style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>
</div>
```

The same with a percentage value instead of a px value:

```css
div.list.list-inset>.item.item-input span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}

div.list.list-inset > *{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list list-inset">
  <label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">-/50 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_50" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_50" name="-/50 mm" 
placeholder="0" style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>
  <label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">50/60 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_50_60" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_50_60" name="50/60 mm" placeholder="0"        
style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>
  <label class="item item-input">
<span class="input-label1">60/70 mm</span>
<input type="text" id="prc_mm_60_70" style="text-
align:right; background-color:transparent;" disabled/>                      
<input type="number" id="mm_60_70" name="60/70 mm" 
placeholder="0" style="text-align:right;"/>                     
</label>
</div>
```